# C# program wont be executed from Java

Tags: java, c#, windows, batch-file, command-line

I have this C# program i made and while i can run it fine by clicking the exe file or by clicking on a batch file, I cant start up the program on a java program I made to run it. I have tried this line of code and couldn't get the software to run.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nameOfTheExeFile");
```

or set it to the batch file i made that starts the program.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nameOfTheBatchFile");
```

Now the interesting thing is when I try it with the batch file i get an error saying that the file cannot be found but when i double click the batch file it will start the exe file just fine.

I have even tried to use Process but I am not getting any luck with that process as well

```
List cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "ProgramName.exe"});

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);

Process p = pb.start();
```

Strange thing is i dont get any error at all. Even when i try unit testing i don't any error's at all. Is there a process I am missing or something ? I am lost on what to do.

Update:

When i check on the task manager i can see that the program is running but not the exe version. I see ProgramName.vshost.exe ,  is there a reason for this to be showing and not the exe file ?

Comment: Can ProgramName.exe be found on your PATH?

Comment: Yes it can and it is, i dont get a errror saying that the file is not there or that i can't find the batch file. And the batch file is in the same directory as the exe file.

Comment: I have the directory set right i made sure of that as i can set the directory and the list and still find the batch file

Comment: Do you have access to the repertory where the file is located ? Som times, things like this can block your way

Comment: I thought i do, but then again i am not sure, The Junit testing when i try to use the batch file i get the windows error saying the exe file can't be located. But i can run it fine just by clicking on the batch file. I do not know why that is happening.

Comment: One thing though I only get the windows error when i add the command start on the batch file. I can leave just the exe name in there and just double clicking the batch file either with the start or without it i can run the program just fine. Still not liking it when java tells it to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your program is command line program you need to start it from cmd. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start nameOfTheBatchFile");
```

Batch file:

```
start cmd.exe /k "nameOfExeFile"
exit
```

Comment: If the path is wrong wouldn't I get a null error? I am not getting that error. other then when i try to run it from the batch file.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nameOfTheExeFile"); will give you IOException but that processbuilder won't throw any exceptions even if the file is not found. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Well that is odd when i try that I am getting a file doesn't exist error but why would java give me that, and before you ask yes the exe file is there :P , I tried that with the batch file and while i can still run the batch file the exe file doesn't want to run.

Comment: Can you post the output of the code i posted above?

Comment: the output is just a windows popup prompt saying windows cannot find the program. Thats when i use your example and try it with the batch file.

Comment: I mean the output for the first 3 lines of code i have in my answer.

Comment: I will upload the error code on this. Its strange when i try the batch file i get no error but with the exe it hates it all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68917/discussion-between-gilbert-v-and-findarkside).