# java ProcessBuilder doesn't work

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute batch file in java.

My source is below:

```
List<String> comm = new ArrayList<String>();
comm.add("cmd");
comm.add("c:/Users/cointreau/workspace/pmd-bin-5.3.2/pmd-bin-5.3.2/bin/pmd.bat");
comm.add("-d");
comm.add("C:\\Users\\cointreau\\workspace\\counter\\src\\Counter.java");
comm.add("-f");
comm.add("xml");
comm.add("-R");
comm.add("java-codesize");
comm.add("-r");
comm.add("C:\\Users\\cointreau\\workspace\\counter\\report.xml");

ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( comm );
Process process = probuilder.start();

//Read out dir output
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}

//Wait to get exit value
try {
     int exitValue = process.waitFor();
     System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the original command line is this,

```
c:/Users/cointreau/workspace/pmd-bin-5.3.2/pmd-bin-5.3.2/bin/pmd.bat -d C:\\Users\\cointreau\\workspace\\counter\\src\\Counter.java -f xml -R java-codesize -r C:\\Users\\cointreau\\workspace\\counter\\report.xml`
```

`pmd.bat` is the batch file what i want to execute and the remainders are just parameters for the bat file.

The only output I can see is just `exit Value is 1`.

When I execute this command line in cmd, it runs properly but not in my java source.

What should I do?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you check what is the content of `process.getErrorStream()`, `process.getInputStream()` and `process.getOutputStream()`?

Comment: ... and what do you mean by "runs properly"? what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Check this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970455/c-sharp-program-wont-be-executed-from-java/27971290#27971290

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I meant... The batch file makes the report file when I execute in cmd.

Comment: "c:/Users/..."=>"c:\\Users\\..."

Comment: @DavidePastore I edited. `exit value is 1` is the output, but when I changed as the comment by @Alexei Kaigorodov, output is changed. Like `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `/C` option to carry out the batch command

```
comm.add("cmd");
comm.add("/c");
comm.add("c:/Users/cointreau/workspace/pmd-bin-5.3.2/pmd-bin-5.3.2/bin/pmd.bat");
...
```